# Parenting an Object's Lifetime

Tags: c++, scope, stl, lifetime

**tl;dr:** Is there a way to tie an arbitrary object's lifetime to that of another?

**Details:** I commonly deal with the issue described [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205269/create-a-c-style-char-from-a-c-vectorstring), which is that I have a `std::vector<CppThing>` but the API I must use has an entrypoint of the form `foo(const CThing**, int numThings)`. I usually take the same approach as the top answer, which is to have the `std::vector<CppThing>` be the "owner" of the `CppThing`s, and construct a `std::vector<CThing*>` using the `CppThing::as_cthing()` method. Unfortunately, the pointers in the new vector become invalidated if the original vector or its elements are modified, or it goes out of scope. It's also difficult to abstract this detail over function call boundaries, e.g. `std::vector<CThing*> MakeThings() {...}`.

Is there a way to tie the lifetime of the owning container to that of the `CThing*` vector, or create an object that encapsulates both, but forwards all its methods to just one of the object interfaces as const?

Example 1:

```
std::vector<CThings*> MakeThings() {
  std::vector<CppThings> v = ...
  std::vector<CThings*> ret;
  for (const auto& x : v) ret.push_back(x.as_cthing());
  InjectLifetime(/*of*/ v, /*into*/ ret);
  return std::move(ret);
} // v goes out of scope but its destructor is not called until ret's is called
```

I suspect the above is impossible from a language perspective, as scope lifetime must be determinable at compile-time, and what happens if you put the `Inject` call in a branch?

Example 2:

```
SomeContainer<std::vector<CThings*>, std::vector<CppThings>> MakeThings() {
  std::vector<CppThing> v = ...
  std::vector<CThing*> cv;
  for (const auto& x : v) cv.push_back(x.as_cthing());
  SomeContainer<std::vector<CThings*>, std::vector<CppThings>> ret;
  ret.SetInterfaceObject(std::move(cv));
  ret.AddHolderObject(std::move(v));
  return ret;
}
...
auto cthings = MakeThings();
cthings.data(); // cv.data()
cthings.size(); // cv.size()
cthings.clear(); // compile error - method not const
```

Basically, I want a `std::tuple` that forwards all methods to a particular element, and just uses the tuple-ness to tie objects together. It seems like this would be easy to solve by deriving from `std::vector` but everything I've read says that doing so is fraught with peril.

Comment: So something along of shared pointer ? An pointer that is tied to a memory that 2 objects can manipulate ? So shared pointer with an read,write,clear, init flags?

Comment: @Danilo No, a single object that encapsulates multiple objects but behaves as if it's just one of its child objects. std::tuple would fit the bill but it has no forwarding ability.

Comment: The function could return a `std::pair<std::vector<CppThing>, std::vector<CThings*>>` where the two local `vector`s are moved into the returned `pair`.

Comment: Are you allowed to derive from `CThings`?

Comment: Presumably you mean `const CThing**`

Comment: @Lightness yes; updated

Comment: @Beta `CThing` is a struct or built-in type. E.g. `std::string` and `char*` or `mylib::GpuAllocation` and `void*`.